# Pointer events target is always the outer-most Polymer element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer, shadow-dom, pointer-events

I am porting 
[polymer-ui-card](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-ui-card/blob/master/polymer-ui-card.html) from JS to Dart.

A difference is that in our project (by convention) we have an additional polymer element (app-element) that contains the entire application.

**In JavaScript it looks like**

```dart
<body unresolved>
  <div id="cards">
    <polymer-ui-card swipeable>Swipe Me!</polymer-ui-card>
    <polymer-ui-card swipeable>Swipe Me!</polymer-ui-card>
    <polymer-ui-card></polymer-ui-card>
    <polymer-ui-card swipeable>Swipe Me!</polymer-ui-card>
    <polymer-ui-card></polymer-ui-card>
  </div>
  ..
</body>
```

**our Dart port looks like**

```dart
<body unresolved>
  <app-element></app-element>
</body>
```

**app-element** has the content the body tag has in JS

```dart
<polymer-element name='app-element'>
  <template>
    <div id="cards">
      <polymer-ui-card swipeable>Swipe Me!</polymer-ui-card>
      <polymer-ui-card swipeable>Swipe Me!</polymer-ui-card>
      <polymer-ui-card></polymer-ui-card>
      <polymer-ui-card swipeable>Swipe Me!</polymer-ui-card>
      <polymer-ui-card></polymer-ui-card>
    </div>
  </template>
  ..
<polymer-element>
```

**polymer-ui-card** (same in JS and Dart)

```dart
<polymer-element name="polymer-ui-card" attributes="swipeable noCurve"
on-trackstart="{{trackStart}}" on-track="{{track}}" on-trackend="{{trackEnd}}" on-flick="{{flick}}">
```

The problem here is that the target for all pointer-events is the `<app-element>` instead of the `<polymer-ui-card>` elements.

Is this by design, or is this a problem that might be Dart only, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [event retargeting](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#event-retargeting) it's no longer possible to talk about the `target` of an event without context.

Where the event listener is registered determines the scope of the DOM nodes that are identified on the event object.

If you put event listeners on `<app-element>` it will always be the target, because it has no children in the document scope.

Comment: As shown in my code, the event listener is on `polymer-ui-card` but `polymer-ui-card` doesn't receive any of these events (event handlers are not called). When I put the `on-xxx` event markup on `app-element`, `app-element` event handlers are called. Click works fine, this seems only to be an issue with pointer events. Maybe this is only an issue with Polymer.dart but before filing a bug I would like to know if this is somehow by design or if this should work.

Comment: I have the same issue with polymer-ui-toggle-button. `on-click` works everywhere but `on-tap` only works when `polymer-ui-toggle-button` is not inside another polymer-element.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Polymer.dart. Composing elements inside of other elements / shadow-dom should not effect event targetting.